# Oracle: using enum / binary values to enhanche performance

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have often to deal with data that may assume just a few values. I think Oracle should use 16 bytes to keep a VARCHAR2(16) (on an index or on a table).

I could use a FK but it implies Oracle to check that values exists on another table. I'd prefer using just computation and RAM. And it's less readable.

If I replace that VARCHAR2(16) with a number or an enum, or a CHAR(1), I would waste just one to 4 bytes. When I've got 4 million rows maybe it could help to avoid wasting space.
It could have a significant effect on performance?

I also imagine a scenario where where field could be used at the 4° position in my indexes (it's not selective. I think I would use just a few).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you're optimizing the wrong thing.

Let's say you have 4 million rows in your table and you manage to save an average of 10 bytes of storage per row by using a NUMBER or CHAR(1) field, which are harder to understand but take less storage.  You've saved 40 entire megabytes!  Woo-hoo!!!  And that 40 megabytes, at current storage pricing, is...totally flipping irrelevant.

You're talking a saving measured in PENNIES.  The amount of time that someone will spend trying to figure out your ENUM, or the meaning of a CHAR(1) field, or the correct interpretation of a NUMBER field, is measured in DOLLARS.  For example, if it takes a contractor one minute **per year** to comprehend the compressed field ("Ummm...does a status of 'O' mean Open, or Out-Of-Stock...or is that a zero...and what does zero mean again?"), at $120/hour consulting rates, you've already spent more ($2) on trying to figure out the compressed field than was saved on the storage.

What you're suggesting made perfect sense back in the 1970's (an era I remember well, thanks) where storage was expensive and not plentiful - you saved every byte you could, compressed fields, used 2-digit years (remember those, anyone? :-), and used every trick you could to save space.  Nowadays storage is cheap and plentiful.  I've got network drives available measured in TERABYTES!  Spending developer time to save relatively miniscule amounts of storage is wasteful in terms of "time spent trying to interpret the results", which results in "dollars spent for the time involved".  Spell things out as clearly as possible and make things as easy to interpret as possible.  YMMV.

Comment: 2-digit years? I was part of a project written in COBOL back in the early 90's where the year was stored with a single digit because the records would only be stored for a maximum of 4 years.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - what can I say?  We were profligate in our use of storage.  (Hangs head in shame).

Comment: I think at the size of an index that could be moved to ram. Do you think it doesn't help the same?

Comment: It sounds like you are in the design stage of your project and thus I suspect you do not have any actual performance problems to address.  If you wish to make your life as simple as possible, and perhaps even to guarantee the best possible performance of your application, in my opinion you will do best to produce the clearest, simplest, most normalized design you can possibly produce.  Until you have a performance problem you cannot address it because you don't know where the performance problems will occur.  Good luck.